# How is turtlebot3 able to transfer 5 different msgs with 115200 baud rate?

Tags: c++, ros

I am going through the code of [turtlebot3_core](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_burger/turtlebot3_core/turtlebot3_core.ino) on ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR git page.

The turtlebot3 is publishing 5 different msgs which are; TransformStamped, SensorState, Imu, Odometry and JointState.

**The message sizes are;**

- turtlebot3_msgs::SensorState sensor_state_msg - **28 bytes**
- sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg - **344 bytes**
- geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel_rc100_msg - **72 bytes**
- nav_msgs::Odometry odom - **112 bytes**
- sensor_msgs::JointState joint_states - **88 bytes**

The total size of the publishing msgs are around 644bytes (if I am not wrong about the sizes). In [turtlebot3_core_config.h](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_burger/turtlebot3_core/turtlebot3_core_config.h), I saw that the publish rates are **30Hz** and for IMU it is **200Hz**. The total baud rate needed is way up more than **115200**. How does turtlebot3 achive this? What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, exactly? Also, you can use `rostopic bw /topic` to check the bandwidth used by the messages.

Comment: I am running same code which they provided on turtlebot3_core.ino, but on a STM32F446re. I am getting a "wrong checksum for topic id and msg" warning on serial_node.py and 'rostopic hz' gives me around 10hz for every topic. I decreased the publish rates to 10Hz (turtlebot3_core_config.h) and the warning is gone. So I assumed that 115200 baud is not enough  for 5 different publishers at the rate of 30Hz.